# Geometry Problem with Tangent Circles Amd Trapezoids

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

[image]

I think the drawing is very self explanatory besides the fact $MN$ is the distance from the touching point of the circles to the common tangent line.

I need to show $MN=\frac{2rR}{R+r}$ which I don't know how to do. The only progress I did is to show the following triangle is a right triangle
[image]

and I could perahps use that $MN$ is the geometric mean of the projections of the sides over the tangent line, which I found no way to do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let angle ECD be $\theta$

Then $$\cos\theta=\frac{R-r}{R+r}=\frac{MN-r}{r}$$

From this the result follows immediately

Comment: So you basically used a variation of the Intercept theorem! Very nice!